# HTML/CSS: display images from linux localhost(firefox)

Tags: html, css, linux, firefox

How can i display images from localhost in a simple html page, in  firefox web browser ?

"file:///home/xuser/work/helico.jpeg" doesn't work.

Comment: If the file itself is called up from localhost too, you don't need the "file:" protocol. So, what's the URL of the file?

Comment: Easiest way is to put your HTML document and images in the same directory and reference them like `<img src="imagefilename.jpg">`. Or you can put the images in a directory called `images` or whatever, and reference them in the HTML like `<img src="images/imagefilename.jpg">`

Comment: localhost is the network hostname for 127.0.0.1 … you can't access it with the file: URL scheme because that bypasses the network entirely

Comment: If a file URI doesn't work it is because either (1) You just got it wrong or (2) You ran into a security restriction. There isn't enough information in the question to tell which.

Comment: I would like to not have to put images in the same directory as the code.

Comment: Maybe if i create a symlink in the html code directory , it could work ?

Comment: If I may ask is there any reason why you don't want the image in the same directory as your code?

Comment: @user-707 If you don't want to move the images to the /var/www folder, how about moving the html file to the ~/work folder?

Answer (score 1):

It would be easier of you put the images In your root folder since you are going to be working with localhost

```
<img src="img/pic.png">
```

But if you would like to get the image from your systems localhost that is somewhere outside root folder it can be pretty stressful at time as you might need to know the image path and might also need to go back a couple of folders. Something like this depending on your image path

```
  <img src="../../../../../../../../../image/pic.png">
```

So it is good you put the image in you root folder for easy access.

Comment: Please use my path in your example:`/home/xuser/work/helico.jpeg`

Answer (score 0):

If you are running it in linux and it is hosted locally, we assume that your project is in **var/www/html**.

So if you want to access **/home/xuser/work/helico.jpeg**, you need to move up 4 times before reaching the **home/** folder.

To move up, use `../` at the beginning of your path. And since you need to move up 4 times, use it four times before the **/home/xuser/work/helico.jpeg**.

Your link or path should be `../../../../home/xuser/work/helico.jpeg`

Try this one. This *may* or *may not* work.

Comment: Well, that doesn't work,i just created a symlink in the html folder.